# Двоеточие, запятая

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Какой знак препинания вы поставите в этом предложении? Тогда казалось(:,) он питается не картофельным супом и квашеной капустой, а одними лишь балладами и гимнами.

Сразу скажу: это предложение из текста тотального диктанта. Запятую посчитали за ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Тогда казалось: он питается не картофельным супом и квашеной капустой, а одними лишь балладами и гимнами.**

**Ставим двоеточие в БСП**, в Нацкорпусе много таких примеров:

...дали по сто граммов водки ― половина граненого стакана. **Мне тогда казалось:** очень много…  [Георгий Арбатов. Человек Системы (2002)]

**Тогда казалось:** еще немного усилий ― и раскроются тайны управляемого термоядерного синтеза... [Георгий Афанасьев. 1987]

**Запятая ставится** в СПП или при обособлении вводного предложения "как тогда казалось":

**Тогда казалось,** что проще полететь на Луну, чем поехать учиться за границу. **Как тогда казалось**, проще полететь на Луну, чем поехать учиться за границу.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) "**Казалось"**  в функции вводного слова может занимать позицию как в начале, так и в  середине предложения, например: **Казалось**, он питается не картофельным  супом и квашеной капустой, а одними лишь балладами и гимнами.

2) **"Тогда казалось"** можно определить как вводное предложение, но это просто сделать в середине предложения, например: Он, **тогда казалось**,  питается не картофельным  супом и квашеной капустой, а одними лишь балладами и гимнами.

3) **Функция "тогда казалось" в начале предложения**  не так ясна, и это, пожалуй, единственная претензия к этому варианту. Я думаю, что считать его ошибочным неправильно, но в учебных текстах лучше поставить в середину предложения, чтобы не было причин для взаимонепонимания.

Comment: А как обосновать, что с запятой - _ошибка_? Без слова "тогда" ошибки явно нет.

Comment: Ответ дан в дополнении

Comment: Вводное слово " казалось" в начале предложения "по значению приближается к простому предложению в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения с зависимыми отношениями"  Розенталя. Д.Э.

Comment: Т.е. возможна постановка запятой. Смущает только слово "тогда".

Comment: Без  "тогда" мы имели бы обычное вводное слово. Кстати, с точки зрения интонации, запятая  для "тогда казалось" подходит больше, так как двоеточие требует понижения тона и удлиненной паузы, а в случае запятой   пауза только слегка обозначена.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как они объясняют постановку двоеточия в этом предложении.

Между частями бессоюзного сложного  предложения ставится двоеточия, так оно передает изъяснительные отношения.В первой части есть слово со значением мысли "казалось", после которого можно поставить союз что. Это предложение является аналогом сложноподчиненного изъяснительного предложения. **Тогда казалось, что он питается...**  В ​бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении изъяснения допустимо употребления тире вместо двоеточия( особенно в художественной литературе). Слово казалось является сказуемым  первой части, а не вводным словом, т. к. при нем есть зависимое слово **тогда, ср.: Тогда... он питается.** *Структура предложения без сказуемого казалось нарушается. ​Поэтому невозможна постановка запятой после глагола казалось ​и его выделение с обеих сторон. ​*

P.S.

Но! Они упустили один нюанс. 
При глаголах чувственного восприятия допускается постановка запятой
"если пишущий не намерен выразить предупреждение" (Правила русской
орфографии и пунктуации... С. 261). **Слово "казаться" включает в свою
семантику указание на чувственное восприятие.**