# Тире или запятая в подобных примерах?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, тире, бсп

Есть у Розенталя два правила:

1)
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm#%D0%B7_03

> **[Тире ставится] если вторая часть** (нередко неполное предложение) **имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта** (см. §117, п. 2), например: Овца же говорит – она всю ночь спала (Крылов); Тишина была такой полной и угрюмой, а небо таким душным, что мальчику казалось – раздайся хоть один только резкий звук – и в природе произойдет что-то страшное: смерч, ураган, землетрясение (Катаев); Вчера на соседнем зимовье рассказывали – медведь человека задрал (Арбузов); Кто-то скребется, мне показалось – мышь; Но вижу – не слушается она меня; Ты позвони в квартиру, бабушка спросит – кто, назовись;

2. 

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm#%D0%B7_02

> [Двоеточие ставится]если в первой части посредством глаголов видеть, смотреть, слышать, понимать, узнать, чувствовать и т.п. делается предупреждение о том, что далее последует изложение какого-либо факта или какое-нибудь описание (в этих случаях между обеими частями обычно можно вставить союз что), например: Пополз я по густой траве вдоль по оврагу, смотрю: лес кончился, несколько казаков выезжают из него на поляну (Лермонтов); Ты сам заметил: день ото дня я вяну, жертва злой отравы (Лермонтов); Помню также: она любила хорошо одеваться и прыскаться духами (Чехов); Я тебе определенно скажу: у тебя есть талант (Фадеев); Он верит: для его солдат и долгий путь вперед короче короткого пути назад (Симонов). **Но (без интонации предупреждения перед второй частью): Слышу, земля задрожала (Некрасов) – запятая вместо двоеточия**;

Жирным выделил то, что мне интересно. Как я вижу, два правила в схожих ситуациях советуют ставить разные знаки: одно — запятую, другое — тире. Но наверняка же можно разграничить случаи подстановки того и другого знака. Но мне как-то сложновато это сделать. Вот примеры у Розенталя — один с запятой, друго с тире:

1. ***Но вижу – не слушается она меня.***
2. ***Слышу, земля задрожала.***

Объяснения, почему в первом случае нужно тире, а во втором запятая, я не нашёл.

А что вы думаете по этому поводу? Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение этой проблемы. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: Игорь,но ведь у Розенталя сказано: если есть интонация предупреждения ставим тире. Но без интонации предупреждения перед второй частью ставим запятую. Примеры у вас.

Comment: Серж, вы не совсем внимательно прочитали. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, еще раз. Тире ставится, если в первой части "НЕ содержится интонационного предложения...".

Comment: Серж, иначе говоря, почему тогда, по-вашему, там должно стоять тире? Если вторая часть предложения имеет изъяснительное значение и между ними есть пауза и интонация предупреждения, ставится ДВОЕТОЧИЕ.

Comment: Если ваш вопрос сводится лишь к тому, почему вместо двоеточия употребляется тире, тогда скажу. Во многих случаях тире и двоеточие вариантивно. Об этом пишет и Лопатин и Розенталь. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=185#pp185

Comment: Серж, пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательнее мой вопрос. Я спрашиваю, почему в одной и той же ситуации Розенталь советует ставить разные знаки препинания. Разницы в примерах, приведенных Розенталем, я не нашёл.

Comment: Тире более агрессивный знак, и даже в тех примерах с двоеточиями,  которые вы привели, можно поставить тире.  Двоеточие именно оправданно там, где наиболее ярко проявляется его изяснительно-пояснительная функция. Розенталь и говорит, что тире ставиться, если нет предупредительной паузы.

Comment: Что касается запятой. Я как-то спрашивал специалистов Граммы.ру об этом пункте, когда возник спорный вопрос относительно одного предложения из Тотального диктанта. Они ответили, что не совсем понимают этот пункт в справочниках. Иначе говоря, искать ответ на этот вопрос не имеет смысла, если даже лингвисты такого уровня не понимают этот пункт.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Но вопрос в том, что корректнее использовать: запятую или тире?

Comment: Если основываться на справочниках, в одних и тех же случаях возможны оба варианта. Хотя, как я уже сказал, не все лингвисты признают запятую в этом случае. Думаю, все же лучше использовать тире. Если, конечно, вы не передаете устную речь на письме.

Comment: Как можно что-то не признавать, если это активно используется в письменной речи? Повсеместно. Между частями в бсп, где вторая часть несёт изъяснительное значение, но нет характерной паузы и интонации для двоеточия, ставится запятая. Что здесь отрицать?

Comment: Дело в том, что в этой позиции более характерна постановка тире, а не запятой.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440204/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f

Comment: Почитайте схожий вопрос. И вот на этот вопрос научный руководитель Граммы.ру ответила вот что.

Comment: Правил русской орфографии пунктуации" действительно содержит такое примечание: "При глаголах, выражающих чувственное восприятие, возможна и постановка запятой — если пишущий не намерен выразить предупреждение: Слышу, с полей донеслась жалейка, ветер дыханье полей принес (Лис)". И вот здесь, как Вы понимаете, начинается лукавство. Во-первых, казаться все-таки впрямую не относится к глаголам чувственного восприятия (таким, как видеть, слышать и т. п.).

Comment: Во-вторых, примечание к правилу выглядит исключительно невнятным. Я, признаться, совсем не понимаю, что означает "пишущий намерен или не намерен выразить предупреждение". Поэтому воспользоваться этим описанием для обоснования постановки запятой довольно затруднительно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В письменных источниках действительно встречаются все **три варианта** оформления **изъяснительной** части в БСП: **двоеточие, тире, запятая**. Как верно замечено, мы наблюдаем это в сходных по структуре предложениях. Более того, одно и то же предложение можно записать с тремя разными знаками.  Отметим, что **это факты**, где согласие специалистов по лингвистике не требуется.
2. Далее **тоже факты** (примеры взяты из Нацкорпуса), то есть это выбор автора.  Писатели, вероятно, больше знают о языке, чем лингвисты, хотя бы на интуитивном уровне.

(1) Двоеточие.  Я вот вчера шел по парку. **Слышу:** сзади ровно она (кошка) мявкает. Остановился. А она стоит и смотрит на меня во все глаза. Забрали его, говорю, Кася, больше его уж тут не будет, и не жди. А она смотрит на меня, как человек, и в глазах слезы. Мне даже страшно стало.

(2) Тире: Вдруг я **слышу** ― сзади опять дверь щелкнула.

(3) Запятая: **Слышу**, кто-то окликает меня.

3. Все три фразы произносятся с **разной интонацией** и имеют **разные смысловые** оттенки. В первом предложении  сделана пауза (остановка голоса), мы как бы вместе с героем прислушиваемся к звукам, пытаемся их распознать. Во втором случае события излагается в ускоренном темпе, там мы присутствуем с автором на месте действия, которое разворачивается на наших глазах. Пауза обозначена, но это не та интонация, которая останавливает, она, напротив, передает движение. В третьем предложении пауза только намечена,  фактически это вводное слово, обозначающее источник информации. Общий тон повествования спокойный.

Всё сказанное – это  не факты, а  **мнение читателя**, на которое я имею право и где мне также не требуется разрешение кого-либо.

4. А теперь переходим **к правилам Розенталя.** Не всегда они четко изложены: многое в них недосказано, многое отредактировано теми же филологами, так что надо уметь читать между строк.  При описании интонации я дополнительно воспользуюсь учебником по современному  синтаксису, так как там четко обозначена **характеристика каждого вида.**

Итак, **двоеточие**. Используется для обозначения изъяснительных  и пояснительных отношений в БСП.  (1) Интонация **нисходяще-нисходящая, с неполным понижением голоса в первой части.** Это то, что Розенталь называет интонационным предупреждением.

В том же учебнике описаны еще два вида интонации. (2) Интонация **нисходяще-нисходящая с полным понижением голоса** перед второй частью, пунктуация: тире или запятая. *Дорога была плохая – людей в кузове швыряло из стороны сторону.  Работа не волк, в лес не убежит*. (3)  **Интонация восходяще-нисходящая**, пунктуация: тире, реже запятая. Область применения: сопоставление (противопоставление) и взаимообусловленные отношения: *Ты богат – я очень беден. Поспешишь – людей насмешишь. Останетесь одни – тогда и живите, как хотите.*

Это все еще официальная (разрешенная) информационная часть.

5. А дальше **terra incognita,**  делайте выводы сами.  Можете здесь остановиться,  можете искать собственный путь. В качестве путеводной звезды могу предложить следующую фразу: «Верны те суждения и теории, которые оправдывают себя **на практике»**.  Другого **критерия истины** пока не придумали, поэтому я не верю в «теорию агрессивности тире».

Я же познакомлю вас со своими «интеллектуальными упражнениями».  Итак, основной характеристикой  интонации при выборе знака является  **не пауза, а движение голоса (тона), оно определяет тип интонации**.

Мы видим, что тире может соответствовать двум совершенно разным типажам, условно назовем эти варианты как  **тире разделительное и тире присоединительное**. И вот присоединительное тире имеет тот  же тип интонации, что и двоеточие (нисходяще-нисходящую),  это тире и  есть «агрессивное», именно оно конкурирует с двоеточием. Но этот тип интонации можно обозначить **и запятой**, различие будет в длительности пауз, в ударении, но только не в тоническом плане.

6. **А теперь рассмотрим нашу задачу,** где используются три разных знака.  Мы уже видели, что тип интонации  во много зависит от движения тона **в первой части**.  С двоеточием все понятно, это первый тип (нисходяще-нисходящая). **А изъяснительное тире?** Этот вариант в учебнике не рассмотрен, так что слушаем фразу  внимательно» «*Вдруг я слышу ― сзади опять дверь щелкнула»*. Я полагаю, что интонация восходяще-нисходящая:  нет здесь понижения голоса и этот вариант резко отличается от пояснительной (предупредительной)  интонации для двоеточия. Отметим, что **пауза** при разделительном тире обозначена **чётко** (в отличие от тире присоединительного).

**А запятая?**  Я думаю, на этом (фактически вводном)  слове тон вообще не изменяется, то есть мы не выделяем его ударением, только обозначаем небольшую паузу. Разумеется,  здесь тоже **нет интонации предупреждения.**

7. **Вот и ответ.**

При отсутствии предупредительной интонации может ставиться **как тире, так и запятая**, но интонационно эти варианты  т**оже различаются между собой,** причем различаются **существенно**.  И передают разные **смысловые оттенки**, которые хорошо чувствует автор и должен так же хорошо почувствовать читатель. А лингвистам надо  сначала разобраться с существующей практикой письма, а потом уже делать какие-либо выводы.

Comment: Sharon, правила требуют редакции. Вы правы. Просто всякий раз думать, какую интонацию выбрать, тоже неверно. Да и читатель вряд ли почувствует.

Comment: Я вам чрезвычайно благодарен!!! Вы не могли бы подсказать, каким именно учебником вы пользуетесь? Он есть в сети?

Comment: Серж, интонацию легче слышать, чем объяснять. Честно говоря, я собиралась сначала не отвечать, а просто спросить у Игоря,  различает ли он три варианта  по произношению и как он их произносит. Есть ли  там разница в смысловых оттенках? Но, посмотрев комментарии, решила сразу дать ответ.  А к правилам вроде бы и претензий особых нет. Две темы (тире и двоеточие) рассмотрены отдельно,  и в обоих случаях указано, что  двоеточие не ставится при отсутствии интонационного предупреждения.

Comment: В этих случаях ставится тире или запятая, просто  Розенталь не дает для них интонационной характеристики.  А не дает, потому что  не вписывается интонационный анализ в существующие правила, это отдельная большая тема. В идеале  ее надо бы называть интонационно-структурной грамматикой  и излагать в общем виде отдельно от правил, а в правилах просто  использовать эти материалы. Но это дело будущего, а пока эти знания желательно использовать  лично для себя на практике, а про теорию лучше вообще молчать. Дали ссылку на Розенталя, и этого достаточно.

Comment: Игорь, спасибо и вам за прекрасный вопрос, за вашу внимательность и желание защитить свою точку зрения, не совпадающую с мнением авторитетов.  Учебник такой:  Кустова  Г.И.  «Синтаксис современного русского языка». В Сети можно найти издание 2005 года (там три автора),  у меня бумажное издание 2013 года (только один автор), также есть издание  2019 года. Тексты немного разные, но, возможно, изменения не так существенны. https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Sharon, благодарю от души вас! Спасибо, что помогаете нам в этом нелёгком деле — постигать всю глубину русского языка!

Comment: @Sharon Расписал "terra incognita".

Answer (score 0):

**Terra incognita** тут вот в чём.

Есть правило, что если союз "а" или "но" пропущен, то необходимо тире.
Розенталь (пункт 2): http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=311
Есть и другие правила про пропуск союза, где вместо него тоже ставится тире.

В примерах вопроса, если считать, что союз "что" пропущен, аналогично ставится тире — вместо союза. Но союз "что" мог и не задумываться, без него тоже корректно. Тогда и на тире заменять нечего, и ставится просто запятая.

**Ключевым** является то, **задумывался ли союз** "что" в исходном предложении или нет.

Здесь очень тонкая грань. В случае тире — пауза больше, интонация отличается. В случае запятой — пауза короче, а "слышу" становится похожим на вводное слово.

А двоеточие готовит к тому, что дальше будет даваться порция информации — не самая короткая, как и в случае с перечислением.